# Why do some modules have inner classes?

Tags: ruby, oop

I know how a module can be used in a class in Ruby:

```rb
module Calculator 

    def add(a,b)
        a+b
    end

end
```

```
class Watch

    include Calculator

    def time 
        Time.now
    end

end
```

```
w = Watch.new()

puts w.time # 2020-03-11 22:34:01 +0000
puts w.add(3,5) # 8
```

But, sometimes I can see some module has a class inside.  For instance, in Rails, helpers:

```
module MyModule

    class MyClass

        def foo
            puts 'foo'
        end

    end

end
```

### **What's the point of this?**

Why would I have a class inside a module?

Comment: Also, you can define a class within another class, if you want to. It’s unusual in Ruby, but it’s sometimes used when someone wants a class only to be instantiated as a property of an instance of the parent class.

Comment: when you see a module like that which has a class, the reason probably is for namespacing.

Answer (score 3):

Modules can be used that way for scoping purposes. In your example you can refer to `MyClass` from outside the module by `MyModule::MyClass`.

There are several uses for this, like grouping together related classes under a common namespace.

It's better to get more information about this from some Ruby tutorials (for examples and stuff). Check out "[Ruby - Modules and Mixins](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_modules.htm)" for more information.

Comment: If that's scoping purpose, why is module used rather than class? I mean MyModule::MyAnotherModule can be done. why it should be class?

Comment: A `module` in Ruby is often used as a generic namespace. You could use a class, but unless `MyNamespace.new` makes any sense (creating an instance of) then use `module` in preference to `class`. Effectively a `class` is a `module` with special abilities.